# Print escaped representation of a unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, escaping

Similar questions have been asked on stackoverflow, but none of the answers deal with the possibility of having a string with accented characters (e.g. àéï) and special  characters (e.g. tab or carriage return) at the same time.

Take the following 2.7 python function:

```
def print_escaped(string):
    print 1, type(string)
    print 2, string
    print 3, repr(string)
    print 4, string.encode('string_escape')
    print 5, string.decode('utf-8')
    print 6, string.decode('utf-8').encode('unicode_escape')
    print 7, repr(string.decode('utf-8'))
```

When called with the input `abécd\r\t\n` it will print:

```
1 <type 'str'>
2 abécd

3 'ab\xc3\xa9cd\r\t\n'
4 ab\xc3\xa9cd\r\t\n
5 abécd

6 ab\xe9cd\r\t\n
7 u'ab\xe9cd\r\t\n'
```

How can I print this string on the screen as simply `abécd\r\t\n` ? I want to escape all control sequences but leave all "normal" readable codepoints untouched.

Comment: That would not be a valid representation of the string. So you really need that you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: How can the definition line, in the python code, of the string as in `s="abécd\r\t\n"` not be afterwards considered a valid representation of itself? I would even argue that it's its prime representation.

Comment: In Python 2 it would at least be required to be marked as unicode with the `u`. Forgetting it usually end in troubles.

Comment: Actually that's incorrect, you don't have to use the prefixing `u` if you declare the encoding after the shebang or if you are typing into ipython.

Comment: That's a very common misconception about encodings in Python 2.

Comment: What is a misconception? I maintain: you don't have to place a `u` character if you have the line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the same file or if you are using an interactive prompt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150927/discussion-between-xapple-and-klaus-d).

Answer (score 1):

```
mappings = {"\r":"\\r","\n","\\n","\t","\\t",...}
print( "".join(mappings.get(ltr,ltr) for ltr in my_string))
```

or

```
escaped = "\r\n\t..."
print("".join(repr(ltr) if ltr in escaped else ltr for ltr in my_string))
```

or

```
print(re.sub("(\s)",lambda m:repr(m.group(0)),my_string)
```

Comment: But that's the whole point: to get an absolutely exhaustive list of all control sequences. The code you propose doesn't solve the problem and is not valid python because of the triple period on line 1.

Comment: I see now that you edited your answer and included the `\s` option from the `re` package. I hadn't thought of that. It appears `\s` is simply equivalent to any of: `\t\n\r\f\v`. Is that all the control sequences there are?